# Regex code to extract multiple information from a filepath string

Tags: regex

Can anyone help me out with a regex code to extract `2010`, `gf`, `HS` & `cd` from the below string?

```
E:\DWP\DS\Planning Analysis\Projects\2012_Tableau Visualisation Program\4. Strategys Models\BMTS Model\JnnnZzzzz_model results\2010\gfHScd.out
```

Thanks :)

Comment: what tools are you using to run your regex? what are the conditions for `gf`, `HS` & `cd`. Is it two letters each? Is it consecutive small then consecutive caps and the consecutive small till the `.`. More examples would help too...

Comment: I am using it in Alteryx. Yes, they are two letters each. I have to add the year and 'gf' 'HS' & 'cd' as separate columns in the output file.

Comment: I am trying to extract the above information from the filepath string and adding them as separate columns . Hope this helps !

Comment: Is this help? `\\(\d{4})\\(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})\.`

Comment: Excellent!! That's exactly what I was trying to achieve .. Thank you so much Duc Filan

Comment: Ok, so I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Duc Filan - Can you please explain/break-down the code for me ? I am very new to regex and would love to learn more... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is it, I re-post the answer from my comment:

```
\\(\d{4})\\(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})\.
```

```js
const regex = /\\(\d{4})\\(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})\./g;
const str = `E:\\DWP\\DS\\Planning Analysis\\Projects\\2012_Tableau Visualisation Program\\4. Strategys Models\\BMTS Model\\JnnnZzzzz_model results\\2010\\gfHScd.out 
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```